# Change line spacing in Authblk

Tags: setspace, authblk

My author list consumes several lines.  I would like to reduce the spacing between lines, between the authors and their affiliations, and between their affiliations.
I attempted to use the setspace package with the command \setstretch, but this only seems to work in the case where the stretch factor is >1, so I can't figure out how to compress my authblk with this method.

How can the spacings be modified?

My MWE for this author block is here:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}
\large
\title{Title}
\vspace{8 pt}
\setstretch{0.1}
\author[1]{Author 1}
\author[2]{Author 2}
\author[3]{Author 3}
\author[4]{Author 4}
\author[5]{Author 5}
\author[1]{Author 6}
\author[1]{Author 7}
\author[1]{Author 8}
\author[1]{Author 9}
\author[1]{Author 10}
\author[1]{Author 11}
\author[1]{Author 12}
\author[1]{Author 13}
\author[1]{Author 14}
\author[1]{Author 15}
\author[1]{Author 16}
\author[1]{Author 17}
\author[1]{Author 18}
\author[1]{Author 19}
\author[1]{Author 20}
\author[1]{Author 30}
\author[1]{Author 31}
\author[1]{Author 32}
\author[1]{Author 33}
\author[1]{Author 34}
\author[1]{Author 35}
\author[1]{Author 36}
\author[1]{Author 37}
\author[1]{Author 38}
\author[1]{Author 39}
\author[1]{Author 40}
\affil[1]{Affiliation 1}
\affil[2]{Affiliation 2}
\affil[3]{Affiliation 3}
\affil[4]{Affiliation 4}
\affil[5]{Affiliation 5}
\date{}
{\let\clearpage\relax%
\maketitle }
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: \scriptsize doesn't make the authors smaller, in case that's what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do with it, so that is a separate problem.  The problem that I was trying to illustrate was that \setstretch{<stretch_factor>} only seems to change the spacing of the author block if <stretch_factor> is > 1.

Comment: I removed \scriptsize from the example to assist with clarity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `\baselineskip` :

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \baselineskip=12pt
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\large
\title{Title}
\vspace{8 pt}
\setstretch{0.1}
\author[1]{Author 1}
\author[2]{Author 2}
\author[3]{Author 3}
\author[4]{Author 4}
\author[5]{Author 5}
\author[1]{Author 6}
\author[1]{Author 7}
\author[1]{Author 8}
\author[1]{Author 9}
\author[1]{Author 10}
\author[1]{Author 11}
\author[1]{Author 12}
\author[1]{Author 13}
\author[1]{Author 14}
\author[1]{Author 15}
\author[1]{Author 16}
\author[1]{Author 17}
\author[1]{Author 18}
\author[1]{Author 19}
\author[1]{Author 20}
\author[1]{Author 30}
\author[1]{Author 31}
\author[1]{Author 32}
\author[1]{Author 33}
\author[1]{Author 34}
\author[1]{Author 35}
\author[1]{Author 36}
\author[1]{Author 37}
\author[1]{Author 38}
\author[1]{Author 39}
\author[1]{Author 40}
\affil[1]{Affiliation 1}
\affil[2]{Affiliation 2}
\affil[3]{Affiliation 3}
\affil[4]{Affiliation 4}
\affil[5]{Affiliation 5}
\date{}
{\let\clearpage\relax%
\maketitle }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what I wanted.  Can you explain how it works?  It looks like you redefine maketitle, but why do you need an @ for the redefinition.  Why are you using \newpage?  Which page is new?  Why the call to \null?    Why do you have so many % symbols.  What does the tabular environment allow you to achieve?  Sorry about the basic questions, I'm new to this.  Your answer is great.