# How to put multiple author names on more than one line using authblk?

Tags: author, affiliation, authblk

I am putting a paper with multiple authors (more than 4) and their names have to be split between two lines. They have multiple affiliations as well, that's why I wanted to use the authblk package. 
However, I can't figure out how can I put the author names on multiple lines.
Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), with the code you have tried already. This will help others answer your query.

Answer (score 0):

**One way** as defined here --https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487457/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \baselineskip=12pt
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\large
\title{Title}
\vspace{8 pt}
\setstretch{0.1}
\author[1]{Author 1}
\author[2]{Author 2}
\author[3]{Author 3}
\author[4]{Author 4}
\author[5]{Author 5}
\author[1]{Author 6}
\author[1]{Author 7}
\author[1]{Author 8}
\author[1]{Author 9}
\author[1]{Author 10}
\author[1]{Author 11}
\author[1]{Author 12}
\author[1]{Author 13}
\author[1]{Author 14}
\author[1]{Author 15}
\author[1]{Author 16}
\author[1]{Author 17}
\author[1]{Author 18}
\author[1]{Author 19}
\author[1]{Author 20}
\author[1]{Author 30}
\author[1]{Author 31}
\author[1]{Author 32}
\author[1]{Author 33}
\author[1]{Author 34}
\author[1]{Author 35}
\author[1]{Author 36}
\author[1]{Author 37}
\author[1]{Author 38}
\author[1]{Author 39}
\author[1]{Author 40}
\affil[1]{Affiliation 1}
\affil[2]{Affiliation 2}
\affil[3]{Affiliation 3}
\affil[4]{Affiliation 4}
\affil[5]{Affiliation 5}
\date{}
{\let\clearpage\relax%
\maketitle }
\end{document}
```

**Another alternative** as defined @AlanMunn -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/381562/197451

[image]

```
%%%% Proceedings format for most of ACM conferences (with the exceptions listed below) and all ICPS volumes.
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\makeatletter

% Use this command to add an existing supplemental affiliation to an author
% \addauthornote{1} adds n-th additional affiliation mark.   
\newcommand\addauthornote[1]{%
  \if@ACM@anonymous\else
    \g@addto@macro\addresses{\@addauthornotemark{#1}}%
  \fi}

\newcommand\@addauthornotemark[1]{\let\@tmpcnta\c@footnote
   \setcounter{footnote}{#1}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
    \g@addto@macro\@currentauthors{\footnotemark\relax\let\c@footnote\@tmpcnta}}

\makeatother
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables

\setcopyright{rightsretained}

% DOI
\acmDOI{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference
\acmConference[THIS '17]{Some ACM Conference}{July 2017}{Anywhere, USA} 
\acmYear{2017}
\copyrightyear{2017}

\acmPrice{15.00}

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}

\author{Author One}
\additionalaffiliation{%
  \institution{Author 1 Secondary Organization}
  \city{Commonville}
  \state{State}
}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{My Company}
  \streetaddress{1234 Here Ave}
  \city{Location}
  \state{State}
  \postcode{12345}
}
\email{author_one@mycompany.com}

\author{Author Two}
\additionalaffiliation{%
  \institution{Author 2 Secondary Organization}
  \city{Commonville}
  \state{State}
}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{My Company}
  \streetaddress{1234 Here Ave}
  \city{Location}
  \state{State}
  \postcode{12345}
}
\email{author_two@mycompany.com}

\author{Author Three}
\addauthornote{2}

\affiliation{%
  \institution{Other Company}
  \streetaddress{5678 There St}
  \city{Place} 
  \state{State} 
  \postcode{67890}
}


\email{author_three@othercompany.net}

\author{Author Four}
\addauthornote{1}

\affiliation{%
  \institution{Other Company}
  \streetaddress{5678 There St}
  \city{Place} 
  \state{State} 
  \postcode{67890}
}


\email{author_four@othercompany.net}


\begin{abstract}
Here is my abstract
\end{abstract}

\keywords{this, that, another}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```